# how to control url from htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I create seo url using htaccess file.Following are the code in my file

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) article.php?article=$1 [NC,L]
```

My article url is http://www.example.info/article/article_name. after click on url they redirects me to http://www.example.info/home/user12/public_html/article.php?article=article_name.

my all files are located in public_html folder. how i can handle my seo url using .htaccess. please help me to solve this issue. thank you

Comment: I would like to see your PHP code, and I would also like to see how you redirect to the article from the /home/user12 page.

Comment: add opening slash to rewriteRule result, like RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) /article.php?article=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: I only Wright above code in my httaccess file , and wright link as <a href= "http://www.example.info/article/article_name">link </a> in my webpage

Comment: Thank you very much. its work with /.

Comment: `htaccess` only with one `T`!